# Which one is better "iterator" or "for-each loop"

Tags: apex

Ierator and for-each loop both we use for traverse no of items, I have used for-each many times but I am not clear about iterator, means when we should use ierator. I am studying salesforce workbook example..

```
global class CustomIterable implements iterator<Account>{

  public List<Account> accs {get; set;}
  public Integer i {get; set;}

  public CustomIterable(){
     accs =[SELECT Name fROM Account limit 5];
     i = 0;          
   }
  global boolean hasNext(){

        if(i >= accs.size()) {
         return false;
        } else {
         return true;
        }
   }
   global Account next(){

        if(i == 8){return null;}
         i++;
         return accs[i-1];
    }
}
```

//------------

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)
global class IteratorClass{
    public static testmethod void main(){

        IteratorClass obj = new IteratorClass();
        Iterator<Account> acs =  obj.Iterator();
        system.debug(acs);

    }
    global Iterator<Account> Iterator(){

           return new CustomIterable();     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An iterator is useful where you don't want to do all the work (or occupy all the memory) up front and can divide the work of returning values up. So for example the iterator could fetch 10 of a total of 100 objects at once and hand each one back and then fetch the next 10 and so on.

The example you provide is fairly pointless and could be coded better.

An iterator can be used in a for loop but it's less clear and more code:

```
for (Iterator<Account> iter = new CustomIterable(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Account a = iter.next();
    System.debug('iter=' + a)
}
```

than the normal for-each loop:

```
for (Account a : [SELECT Name fROM Account limit 5]) {
    System.debug('list=' + a);
}
```

Note that Apex does **not** support this convenience pattern:

```
for (Account a : new CustomIterable()) {
    System.debug('list=' + a);
}
```

So an "iterator" and a "for each" are different things, not better or worse than each other.

One place where occasionally you may need to write your own `Iterable` is as a return value from [Batchable.start](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm#apex_Database_Batchable_start). But don't use that if SOQL queries are involved as the normal 50,000 record governor limit applies whereas the `start` method that returns `Database.QueryLocator` can query up to 50 million records.

Comment: Thanks Keith for your explanation, actually i had noticed in Batch Apex Start method executes once and execute_method executes more than one times for different set of records. can you suggest a basic example where i can test how internally it is sending set of records one by one...... in my example it display 5 records in one time, so it is not clear to me how can i send bunch of records one by one..... that would be really helpful if you give any example as per my requirement...

Comment: `for (Iterator<Account> iter = new CustomIterable(); iter.hasNext(); )` has better garbage collection than `Iterator<Account> iter = new CustomIterable();    while(iter.hasNext() { ... }`.  Can be useful when you don't need the iterator after the loop.  Also, don't necessarily need `Iterator<Account>` as the type of `iter`.  Can use: `for (CustomIterable iter = new CustomIterable(); iter.hasNext(); )` so you can use all of `iter`'s  methods.

Comment: If you also want your custom Iterator to work in for-loops, please vote: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CSAwQAO